# Access JQuery function outside the declared file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Plz check the below page hieracy on my asp.net mvc app.'

**BookingDetailsForScheduler.aspx**

```
**HTML**

        <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 480px;">
                            <div id="service-selection">
                                <% Html.RenderPartial("MainServices", Model); %>
                            </div>
                            <div id="available-dates">
                                <% Html.RenderPartial("Dates", Model); %>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

    **JS**
     $(document).ready(function () {

      var multiDatesPickerBinding = function () {

    //code goes here
    });

    });
```

**Now my requirement is** this, can I access 'multiDatesPickerBinding' function withing the 'Dates.ascx' page's  javascript code ?

**Dates.ascx**

```
**HTML**

**js**
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        How to access 'multiDatesPickerBinding' ?

});

</script>
```

Comment: You can make global functions in Javascript, but you'd still have a race condition - you don't know which of the ready() functions will be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because that function is defined in the scope of the anonymous function that is the document ready handler, so it's not accessible from the outside.

It's also not clear if it would make sense to access that function even if it were possible. Is `Dates.ascx` meant to be reusable? Then why does it have a hidden dependency? Is it *not* meant to be? Then why don't you put that code inside your booking details view?

Comment: @Sampath: By structuring the code better. I have updated the answer to mention that this way of arranging things doesn't look OK. In general hidden dependencies like this are just bad engineering and will cause problems. I can't be specific because there is not enough information to go on.

Comment: Plz see this thread also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356149/page-reload-issue?noredirect=1#comment28681017_19356149

Comment: My problem is when I put the code as you mentioned,My calendar control 's onSelect method is not working as I mentioned above url.So that's why I have put that code inside the 'Dates.ascx' page.After that it's working.But I need to access the function which are on main page also (for onSelect Method).How can I achieve that ?